# Remove parameters from a URL regardless

Tags: java, http, url, netty

Let's say we have a URL like the following:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=X&b=Y
```

I like to just get `https://www.google.com/search`. There are a few easy ways to do this like so 
`String baseUrl = url.split("?")[0];` What's a better/safe way to do this? Is there something build in?

Comment: Is that way of spliting, an unsafe way? It's good enought to me

Comment: The problems could start when the URL is inserted by the user

Comment: then check for length, check for dots, check for '?' symbols. Then the problem is not the way of extracting the URL part, but that a user could fail in entering

Comment: `split("?")` will not work because the split method takes a regex. To use the split method it must be `split("\\?")[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use URL type, and it's methods.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?q=X&b=Y");


      System.out.println("protocol is " + url.getProtocol());
      // |-> prints: 'https'
      System.out.println("hot is "+ url.getHost()); 
      // url.getAuthority() is valid too, but may include the port 
      // incase it's included in the URL
      // |-> prints: 'www.google.com'
      System.out.println("path is " + url.getPath());
      // |-> prints: '/search'

      //WHat you asked for          
      System.out.println(url.getProtocol()+"://"+ url.getAuthority()+url.getPath());
      // |-> prints: 'https://www.google.com/search'
    }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

> protocol is https
>
> host is www.google.com
>
> path is /search
>
> https://www.google.com/search

Comment: What if the URL includes a port? What if it includes a ref?

Comment: It's a good question, however my answer covers strictly what the person asking wanted. But, answering your question, if the url has a port it should work as well, but getHost() must be used, not getAuthority(). Haven't tried for ref

Comment: Could you write a URL example that could be applied for your 'ref' case? as fas as I know there's a getRef() method too.

Comment: The ref (or fragment) is indicated with '#' sign. The fragment is located after the query (if a query is present). Whether the OP wants to keep the ref is questionable. Example: `http://my.site.org:8080/search?query#ref`

Comment: Yes, I told you, getRef() should work. It would return 'ref' in that case. I was asking you for an example in case there was an special URL you were interested in.

Comment: No need for ref, by ports are needed. Do you know if there is something build into Netty to handle this - I have looking @ the [QueryStringDecoder.java](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/QueryStringDecoder.java)?

Comment: I have no experience in Netty

Answer (score 2):

RFC 3986 (the specification for URIs) contains a regexp you can use: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#regexp

Comment: Is the library that can handle this for me? Netty perhaps?